# Redirect a WordPress contact form to a new page after succeed

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

For my Wordpress site i have a contact form. For analyzing the conversion i want to redirect the contact form to a new page. for example: mypage.com/succes. I tried a lot in the functions.php but nothing is working. Can anybody help me with this?

Contact form part of the funtions.php:

```
    add_shortcode( 'et_pb_contact_form', 'et_pb_contact_form' );
    function et_pb_contact_form( $atts, $content = null ) {
    global $et_pb_contact_form_num;

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'module_id' => '',
            'module_class' => '',
            'captcha' => 'on',
            'email' => '',
            'title' => '',
        ), $atts
    ) );

    $et_error_message = '';
    $et_contact_error = false;
    $contact_email = isset( $_POST['et_pb_contact_email'] ) ? sanitize_email( $_POST['et_pb_contact_email'] ) : '';

    if ( isset( $_POST['et_pb_contactform_submit'] ) ) {
        if ( 'on' === $captcha && ( ! isset( $_POST['et_pb_contact_captcha'] ) || empty( $_POST['et_pb_contact_captcha'] ) ) ) {
            $et_error_message .= sprintf( '<p>%1$s</p>', esc_html__( 'Make sure you entered the captcha.', 'Divi' ) );
            $et_contact_error = true;
        } else if ( 'on' === $captcha && ( $_POST['et_pb_contact_captcha'] <> ( $_SESSION['et_pb_first_digit'] + $_SESSION['et_pb_second_digit'] ) ) ) {
            $et_error_message .= sprintf( '<p>%1$s</p>', esc_html__( 'You entered the wrong number in captcha.', 'Divi' ) );

            unset( $_SESSION['et_pb_first_digit'] );
            unset( $_SESSION['et_pb_second_digit'] );

            $et_contact_error = true;
        } else if ( empty( $_POST['et_pb_contact_name'] ) || empty( $contact_email ) || empty( $_POST['et_pb_contact_message'] ) ) {
            $et_error_message .= sprintf( '<p>%1$s</p>', esc_html__( 'Make sure you fill all fields.', 'Divi' ) );
            $et_contact_error = true;
        }

        if ( ! is_email( $contact_email ) ) {
            $et_error_message .= sprintf( '<p>%1$s</p>', esc_html__( 'Invalid Email.', 'Divi' ) );
            $et_contact_error = true;
        }
    } else {
        $et_contact_error = true;
        if ( isset( $_SESSION['et_pb_first_digit'] ) )
            unset( $_SESSION['et_pb_first_digit'] );
        if ( isset( $_SESSION['et_pb_second_digit'] ) )
            unset( $_SESSION['et_pb_second_digit'] );
    }

    if ( ! isset( $_SESSION['et_pb_first_digit'] ) )
        $_SESSION['et_pb_first_digit'] = $et_pb_first_digit = rand(1, 15);
    else
        $et_pb_first_digit = $_SESSION['et_pb_first_digit'];

    if ( ! isset( $_SESSION['et_pb_second_digit'] ) )
        $_SESSION['et_pb_second_digit'] = $et_pb_second_digit = rand(1, 15);
    else
        $et_pb_second_digit = $_SESSION['et_pb_second_digit'];

    if ( ! $et_contact_error && isset( $_POST['_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted'], 'et-pb-contact-form-submit' ) ) {
        $et_email_to = '' !== $email
            ? $email
            : get_site_option( 'admin_email' );

        $et_site_name = get_option( 'blogname' );

        $contact_name   = stripslashes( sanitize_text_field( $_POST['et_pb_contact_name'] ) );

        $headers[] = "From: \"{$contact_name}\" <{$contact_email}>";
        $headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$contact_email}>";

        wp_mail( apply_filters( 'et_contact_page_email_to', $et_email_to ),
            sprintf( __( 'New Message From %1$s%2$s', 'Divi' ),
                sanitize_text_field( $et_site_name ),
                ( '' !== $title ? sprintf( _x( ' - %s', 'contact form title separator', 'Divi' ), sanitize_text_field( $title ) ) : '' )
            ), stripslashes( wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['et_pb_contact_message'] ) ), apply_filters( 'et_contact_page_headers', $headers, $contact_name, $contact_email ) );

        $et_error_message = sprintf( '<p>%1$s</p>', esc_html__( 'Thanks for contacting us', 'Divi' ) );
    }

    $form = '';

    $name_label = __( 'Name', 'Divi' );
    $email_label = __( 'Email Address', 'Divi' );
    $message_label = __( 'Message', 'Divi' );

    $et_pb_contact_form_num = ! isset( $et_pb_contact_form_num ) ? 1 : $et_pb_contact_form_num++;

    $et_pb_captcha = sprintf( '
        <div class="et_pb_contact_right">
            <p class="clearfix">
                %1$s = <input type="text" size="2" class="input et_pb_contact_captcha" value="" name="et_pb_contact_captcha">
            </p>
        </div> <!-- .et_pb_contact_right -->',
        sprintf( '%1$s + %2$s', esc_html( $et_pb_first_digit ), esc_html( $et_pb_second_digit ) )
    );

    if ( $et_contact_error )
        $form = sprintf( '
            <div class="et_pb_contact">
                <div class="et-pb-contact-message">%11$s</div>

                <form class="et_pb_contact_form clearfix" method="post" action="%1$s">
                    <div class="et_pb_contact_left">
                        <p class="clearfix">
                            <label class="et_pb_contact_form_label">%2$s</label>
                            <input type="text" class="input et_pb_contact_name" value="%3$s" name="et_pb_contact_name">
                        </p>
                        <p class="clearfix">
                            <label class="et_pb_contact_form_label">%4$s</label>
                            <input type="text" class="input et_pb_contact_email" value="%5$s" name="et_pb_contact_email">
                        </p>
                    </div> <!-- .et_pb_contact_left -->

                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <p class="clearfix">
                        <label class="et_pb_contact_form_label">%7$s</label>
                        <textarea name="et_pb_contact_message" class="et_pb_contact_message input">%8$s</textarea>
                    </p>

                    <input type="hidden" value="et_contact_proccess" name="et_pb_contactform_submit">

                    <input type="submit" value="%9$s" class="et_pb_contact_submit">

                    %6$s

                    %10$s
                </form>
            </div> <!-- .et_pb_contact -->',
            esc_url( get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ),
            $name_label,
            ( isset( $_POST['et_pb_contact_name'] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['et_pb_contact_name'] ) : $name_label ),
            $email_label,
            ( isset( $_POST['et_pb_contact_email'] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['et_pb_contact_email'] ) : $email_label ),
            (  'on' === $captcha ? $et_pb_captcha : '' ),
            $message_label,
            ( isset( $_POST['et_pb_contact_message'] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['et_pb_contact_message'] ) : $message_label ),
            __( 'Submit', 'Divi' ),
            wp_nonce_field( 'et-pb-contact-form-submit', '_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted', true, false ),
            $et_error_message
        );

    $output = sprintf( '
        <div id="%4$s" class="et_pb_contact_form_container clearfix%5$s">
            %1$s
            %2$s
            %3$s
        </div> <!-- .et_pb_contact_form_container -->
        ',
        ( '' !== $title ? sprintf( '<h1 class="et_pb_contact_main_title">%1$s</h1>', esc_html( $title ) ) : '' ),
        ( '' !== $et_error_message ? sprintf( '<div class="et-pb-contact-message">%1$s</div>', $et_error_message ) : '' ),
        $form,
        ( '' !== $module_id
            ? esc_attr( $module_id )
            : esc_attr( 'et_pb_contact_form_' . $et_pb_contact_form_num )
        ),
        ( '' !== $module_class ? sprintf( ' %1$s', esc_attr( $module_class ) ) : '' )
    );

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Try [wp_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Comment: Thanks for you reaction. Where in the code can i add this?

Comment: Wherever you intend to redirect the user... Probably in the "form submitted" portion of your code.

Comment: Sorry i still don't get it working. I'm new in PHP so can anybody explain me it a bit more?

Comment: Right after `$et_error_message = sprintf( '<p>%1$s</p>', esc_html__( 'Thanks for contacting us', 'Divi' ) );`

Comment: I feel very stupid but i still don't get it work. On the next line direct after `$et_error_message = sprintf( '<p>%1$s</p>', esc_html__( 'Thanks for contacting us', 'Divi' ) );` i put this line of code : `wp_redirect( 'http://google.com', 301 ); exit;`. and it still not works. The line with the thank you message in html is gone but the page is nog redirecting to a new page. What can it be @AliIdrees?

Comment: By any chance, are you using AJAX to submit this form?

Comment: @AliIdrees i checked the code and i don't see any AJAX referrals or something like that. So i don't think its using AJAX to submit the form. I use a WordPress theme named DIVI. The contactform is standaard in the theme.

Comment: Ok is there anything in your success message page? Other than the code to track conversion?